# What is the relationship between Errors, Exceptions and Interrupts in Python 3?

Tags: python

In Python 3 there are many types of Exception. Some Exception names end with "Error" (for example, `StandardError`, `OverflowError`). Other Exceptions do not end in `Error` (eg. `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`).

Are all Errors derived from the class Exception? Do all Exceptions interrupt program execution?

Is this inheritance tree accurate?

> Errors -> Exceptions -> Interrupt

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupt"?

Comment: interrupt is a os concept to take control form running programs, for example assume progA is running and a clock interrupt occur then os pause progA and go to respond to clock interrupt and then comeback to progA again.

Answer (score 3):

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy):

> `Exception`: All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

So, `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` are meant to terminate the program (and you don't expect `except Exception` to catch them; if you want to catch them, you need to be more specific); `GeneratorExit` is explained in the docs itself.

Answer (score 1):

In python all exceptions are inherited from `BaseException`

For detailed inheritance tree see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)